Including .aar dependencies using .pom file from local directory
I have a .pom and an .aar file. .pom lists dependencies and I'd like to add all those in Android Studio/Gradle.
I've tried adding directory using
{ maven { url = ... } }

and then add an
implementation 'GROUPID:ARTIFACTID:VERSION'

and the .aar gets included, but dependencies do not. Tried adding 'transitive true', but doesn't help either nor does it help adding @pom at the end of implemenntation path like
implementation 'GROUPID:ARTIFACTID:VERSION@pom'

So, what would be the correct way to add both .aar and its dependencies (to an Android project) through a .pom file?

Have you considered importing/installing them to your local Maven repo (mavenLocal())
path ~/.m2/repository using Maven/Gradle commands?

I would copy all directory structure there (with pom and aar) and use mavenLocal? Will try.

No, you use Maven or gradle command to let it install the aar file into local maven repo and create the necessary meta data files. https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/specific-local-repo.html Not sure which command is provided by gradle for the same task.

I see. But the problem is that the online repo is protected and I don't seem to manage authentication using a token. OTOH I have all files locally.

I wasn't talking about an online repo, but your local Maven repo that is stored in your home folder. If you want you can omit maven/gradle and manually install your artifact file: https://geraldonit.com/2018/03/19/manually-installing-a-maven-artifact-in-your-local-repository/

Thanks for the help, it turns out the error was elsewhere (see my answer to myself).

At the end of the day it turns out that I've been misled by the error. It turns out that the library I was trying to run doesn't work on an emulator, but it works on a proper device.
Importing an .aar library from a local directory as described in original post works fine.
